# What is forbidden after pointer-casting a big type to a smaller type in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Say I have a bigger type.

```c
uint32_t big = 0x01234567;
```

Then what can I do for `(char*)&big`, the pointer interpreted as a char type after casting?

1. Is that an undefined behavior to **shift** the address of `(char*)&big` to `(char*&big)+1`, `(char*&big)+2`, etc.?
2. Is that an undefined behavior to both **shift** and **edit** `(char*)&big+1`? Like the example below. I think this example should be an undefined behavior because after casting to `(char*)`, we then have limited our eyesight to a `char`-type pointer, and we ought not access, even change the value outside this scope.

```c
uint32_t big = 0x01234567;
*((char*)&big + 1) = 0xff;
printf("%02x\n\n\n", *((char*)&big+1));
printf("%02x\n\n\n", big);
```

(This pass my Visual C++ compiler. By the way, I want to ask a forked question on that why in this example the first `printf` gives `ffffffff`? Shouldn't it be `ff`?)

3. I have seen a code like this. And this is what I usually do when I need to achieve similar task. Is this UB or not? Why or why not? What is the standard way to achieve this?

```c
uint8_t catcher[8] = { 0 };
uint64_t big = 0x1234567812345678;
memcpy(catcher, (uint8_t*)&big, sizeof(uint64_t));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then what can I do for `(char*)&big`, the pointer interpreted as a char type after casting?

If a `char` is eight bits, which it is in most modern C implementations, then there are four bytes in the `uint32_t` `big`, and you can do arithmetic on the address from `(char *) &big + 0` to `(char *) &big + 4`. You can also read and write the bytes from `(char *) &big + 0` to `(char *) &big + 3`, and those will access individual bytes in the representation of `big`. Although arithmetic is defined to work up to `(char *) &big + 4`, that is only an endpoint. There is no defined byte there, and you should not use that address to read or write anything.

> 1. Is that an undefined behavior to **shift** the address of `(char*)&big` to `(char*&big)+1`, `(char*&big)+2`, etc.?

These are additions, not shifts, and the syntax is `(char *) &big + 1`, not `(char*&big)+1`. Arithmetic is defined for the offsets from +0 to +4.

> 2. Is that an undefined behavior to both **shift** and **edit** `(char*)&big+1`?

It is allowed to read and write the bytes in `big` using a pointer to `char`. This is a special rule for character types. Generally, the bytes of an object should not be accessed using an unrelated type. For example, a `float` object could not be accessed using an `int` type. However, the character types are special; you may access the bytes of any object using a character type.

However, it is preferable to use `unsigned char` for this, as it avoids complications with signed values.

> 3. I have seen a code like this.

It is allowed to read or write the bytes of an object using `memcpy`. `memcpy` is defined to work as if by copying characters.

Note that, while accessing the bytes of an object is defined by the C standard, how bytes represent values is partly implementation-defined. Different C implementations may use different orders for the bytes within an object, and there can be other differences.

> By the way, I want to ask a forked question on that why in this example the first `printf` gives `ffffffff`? Shouldn't it be `ff`?

In your C implementation, `char` is signed and can represent values from −128 to +127. In `*((char*)&big + 1) = 0xff;`, `0xff` is 255 and is too big to fit into a `char`. It is converted to a `char` value in an implementation-defined way. Your C implementation converts it to −1. (The eight-bit two’s complement representation of −1, bits 11111111, uses the same bits as the binary representation of 255, again bits 11111111.)

Then `printf("%02x\n\n\n", *((char*)&big+1));` passes this value, −1, to `printf`. Since it is a `char`, it is promoted to `int` to be passed to `printf`. This produces the same value, −1, but it has 32 bits, 11111111111111111111111111111111. Then you are passing an `int`, but `printf` expects an `unsigned int` for `%02x`. The behavior of this is not defined by the C standard, but your C implementation reads the 32 bits as if they were an `unsigned int`. As an `unsigned int`, the 32 bits 11111111111111111111111111111111 represent the value 4,294,967,295 or `0xffffffff`, so that is what `printf` prints.

You can print the correct value by using `printf("%02hhx\n\n\n", * ((unsigned char *) &big + 1));`. As an `unsigned char`, the bits 11111111 represent 255 or `0xff`, and converting that to an `int` produces 255 or `0x000000ff`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really help me to clarify many things. By the way, I want to ask a detail with respect to the compiler/runtime side.  When I write `(char*)&big+6`, is that the compiler (or OS) will first indeed compute the address, and check whether the corresponding memory location is owned by me, and then decide whether I'm capable of editing the value on there? Or as soon as I write `(char*)&big+6`, the compiler or OS will know that it definitely exceed the range I legally have?

Comment: My point is that, it seems weird that someone (some machine) can know what is the limit of n such that `(char*)&big+n` is readable, because after casting `&big` by using `(char*)`, the information that originally `&big` was a bigger type (and had 4 bytes) should be missed. Only when the machine actually compute `(char*)&big+6` and are going to that address, then it can detect the access by the programmer may be problematic.

Comment: @Eric The machine or the compiler need not check or detect anything. It's the programmer's responsibility. Any access beyond the bounds is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Eric: The C standard does not define the behavior of `(char *) &big + 6` (given that `big` is only four bytes). For some kinds of errors, the C standard might require the compiler to issue a diagnostic message or for a library routine to provide an error code. But when it does not define the behavior at all, there are no requirements on the compiler or the execution of the program. Some compilers might detect that `(char *) &big + 6` is a mistake while compiling the program. In most C implementations, computing the address will not cause a problem by itself…

Comment: … However, when using the address to read or write data, the processor might detect a problem. Modern operating systems mark parts of the virtual address space as usable or not usable in various ways—may be read, may be executed (instructions to be executed may be fetched from that address), may be written. If you read a byte from an address that is not marked as may-be-read or write a byte to an address that is not marked as may-be-written, then the processor will generate a trap…

Comment: … However, since we know `&big` is a readable and writeable address, the only way `&big + 6` can be a protected address is if `big` happens to be on a boundary where the protections change. Most commonly, `big` will be part of a region in memory where other things are also stored, so it is not likely to be the last thing in the region, near where the protections change. So a small error in addressing like this is not likely to be caught by the processor memory protections.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see. Thank you again! I think I begin to have a firmer understanding on pointers and memory. :)

Answer (score -1):

For [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic) (like `printf`) all arguments undergoes [default argument promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) which [promotes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) smaller integer types to `int`.

This conversion will include *sign-extension* if the smaller type is signed, so the value keeps its value.

So if `char` is a signed type (which is implementation defined) with a value of `-1` then it will be promoted to the `int` value `-1`. Which is what you see.

If you want to print a smaller type you need to first of all cast to the correct type (`unsigned char`) then use the proper format (like `%hhx` for printing `unsigned char` values).